# MySQL Data Directory on Network Drive?

Tags: mysql, networking, directory, mysql-workbench, external

I am new to databases and MySQL and am still in the process of learning it. I have been tasked to see if it is possible to store the MySQL Data Directory in a Network Drive... The purpose is to have a backup of the directory and allowing multiple users to point to that particular directory.

I have been able to successfully move the data directory to a different location on my PC but have been unsuccessful when I tried moving the data directory into a Network Drive.

Is it possible to move the data directory into a shared Network Drive, and if so, what steps should I take?

Notes:

- Windows 10
- Attempted moving the directory and editing the my.ini
  file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your approach is not optimal or I'm misunderstanding the question (or whoever gave you the task isn't clear on the best ways to back up MySQL databases). If I were you, I'd put it to whoever asked you to do this task that making plain-text SQL (`*.sql`) dumps of the databases and putting those into the backup directory would be easier/simpler than making a backup of the data directory itself, which contains binary file representations of the databases.

From the [MySQLdump manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html):

> To dump all databases:

```
$ mysqldump --all-databases > dump.sql
```

> To dump only specific databases, name them on the command line and use the `--databases` option:

```
$ mysqldump --databases db1 db2 db3 > dump.sql
```

The `--databases` option causes all names on the command line to be treated as database names. Without this option, `mysqldump` treats the first name as a database name and those following as table names.

> With `--all-databases` or `--databases`, `mysqldump` writes `CREATE DATABASE` and `USE` statements prior to the dump output for each database. This ensures that when the dump file is reloaded, it creates each database if it does not exist and makes it the default database so database contents are loaded into the same database from which they came. If you want to cause the dump file to force a drop of each database before recreating it, use the `--add-drop-database` option as well. In this case, `mysqldump` writes a `DROP DATABASE` statement preceding each `CREATE DATABASE` statement.
>
> To dump a single database, name it on the command line:

```
$ mysqldump --databases test > dump.sql
```

*Exercise for the reader:* Write a script (crontab) or set up a scheduled task to dump the databases and move the output to the network drive.

If that's not what is required, but access to the database by multiple people is, create user accounts using the MySQL Server RDBMS instead. (You might need to configure the server to allow remote access. In that case, remove any `test` or `anonymous`/`blank password` accounts and change the root password to something more secure than `root`, `admin` or `password1`.)